# XPS 13 9315's camera, Bluetooth, power management drivers?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, dell, webcam, xps

First post on the forum so thanks in advance for your help!

I recently bought an XPS 13 9315 with Ubuntu 20.04 preinstalled, but once I got it I immediately formatted it and installed 22.04 as I'm a sucker for the latest features, etc.

Unfortunately, since the update, I have been experiencing a series of driver-related issues, and was hoping someone who had a similar experience could help. Specifically:

1. The webcam does not work. It's not recognized by any browser or other applications (including Cheese)
2. The fan is sometimes noisy for no apparent reason (just browsing and watching videos), which I believe may be related to the lack of proper battery management
3. Bluetooth audio does not recognize any of my headphones as audio devices so they don't show up as output option, so I can't use them

Did anybody experience any of these issues and manage to fix some (or all) of them?

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: Your Dell XPS was probably running an OEM kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you please elaborate a bit? Any chance you know how I could fix these issues?

Comment: Update: I talked to Dell and, despite not being extremely helpful, they did send me a generic guide to install Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell laptops and there's a part about Machine Owner Key (MOK) that seems to hint setting up one would help with receiving third party drivers? I only learned about MOK recently so I didn't set up one when I installed 22.04. Could that be the source of my driver issues?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 22.10 with 6.0.9 kernel The problem with visual glitches on wayland solved
No issues with audio devices
Camera not works. Need to spend more effort to install package manually

Answer (score 0):

So I have this same exact model and What I did was upgrade from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and that worked for me. There is some proprietary drivers and stuff that Dell provides to get everything to work. Support did tell me before that you can use the image on Ubuntu's website. I suspect that if you did you would need to add their custom repos after the fact.

You could try adding these repos to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-psyduck-meta.list that file likely won't exist so you will have to create it. Here are the contents of that file.

```
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ jammy somerville
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ jammy somerville-psyduck
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-psyduck
```

After this run a
$ sudo apt update

Then go check additional drivers. There should be the ability to enable the OEM drivers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgl91.png)

Let me know if that helps.